# FUSE options on 18.04 vs 14.04

Tags: permissions, mount, fuse, ntfs-3g

I have two Ubuntu installations:

1. 14.04 LST (3.13.0-160-generic #210-Ubuntu)
2. 18.04 LST (4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu)

On system #1 (14.04), when a NTFS partition is (auto?)mounted, then the permissions work properly. There are these two lines in `/etc/mtab`:

```
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user="my username")
/dev/sde2 on /media/"my username"/"NTFS partition label" type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

(In the `/etc/fuse.conf` file, all lines are commented out)

On system #2 (18.04), when a NTFS partition is (auto?)mounted, then the permissions do not work properly: everybody got all types of access; all non-directory files are colored green to indicate that they're executables (and they can be "executed", too: for example, if a C source file is "launched" by typing `./"filename".c`, then Ubuntu attempts to execute the lines as a shell script. There are these two lines in `/etc/mtab`:

```
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)    
/dev/sda3 on /media/"my username"/"NTFS partition label" type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

(In the `/etc/fuse.conf` file, all lines are commented out)

On both systems `/etc/fstab` has only two lines in them: the ones which mount the root file system (/) and the swap.

I'm extremely frustrated: I couldn't figure out what is the difference between the two systems as far as FUSE configuration goes. I was entirely happy with the 14.04 setup, and the 18.04 one is killing me.

Please help!